# GRPC Error : Sample C++ code not working [cpp-docs-samples]

Tags: android, c++, grpc, google-speech-api

We are trying to use Google's Speech API on an android device using Native. The objective is to send the audio data via bi-directional streaming API and to receive the results in the form of text.

**Problems we have encountered:**

The following are the errors we are facing at the moment:

```
 1. E GRPC : security_connector.c:665] load_file: {"created":"@1556117117.306042161","description":"Failed to load file","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/load_file.c","file_line":82,"filename":"path/asr/build-grpc-android/ndk-install/share/grpc/roots.pem","referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1556117117.306032213","description":"OS Error","errno":2,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/load_file.c","file_line":58,"os_error":"No such file or directory","syscall":"fopen"}]}

 2. E GRPC : security_connector.c:744] Could not get default pem root certs.

 3. E GRPC : completion_queue.c:254] Operation failed: tag=0x7fc1b19058, error={"created":"@1556117117.306594453","description":"lame client channel","file":"src/core/lib/surface/lame_client.c","file_line":84}
```

**What we expected to happen:**

We expected the API to send the audio data to the server and return back the results in text form.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- The code example `"streaming_transcribe.cc"` was used from the [given
  link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api):
- Protobuf version used: **Protobuf v3.0.0**
- We are performing **cross-compilation** and running it on **Samsung
  Galaxy Note 8 O-OS android**. *The required Google API code was also cross-compiled.*
- We have also added a *JNI layer* to invoke the renamed main function
  from java layer.

**Other information (workarounds we have tried, documentation consulted, etc):**

As this is a simple demo code, no workarounds tried. Documentation consulted is the link itself.

Comment: Here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe.cc#L68 you use google default credential, which reads environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Did you set a value to it, which should be the path of a json file of token? Google search this key for more information.

Comment: For Android client, you might prefer user accounts credential than service accounts credential. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/